# Getting wrong reading special characters from a docx files. I need to get a box of a form

Tags: python, docx

I try to get a special character (a box of a form) from my word document with the docx library. My code is:

```
for position, block in enumerate(documentList):

    if ("EXPL" in normalize_string(block.text) and "PERSON" in normalize_string(block.text)):
        table = documentList[position+3].table
        text = table.cell(1,1).text
```

And the result is the normal text without a box of a form.

THANKS!